# Regex is dividing a single statement?

Tags: php, regex

I am having a difficult time with regex, I am getting a separate "revenue" without any of the previous matching.

```
$string = "FY2013 EPS, FQ 2012 revenue";
preg_match_all("/F[Y|Q]\s?\d{4}\sEPS|revenue/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => FY2013 EPS [1] => revenue ) )
```

What I was expecting:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => FY2013 EPS [1] => FQ 2012 revenue ) )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It reads as *OR revenue* - you want to use:

```
"/F[Y|Q]\s?\d{4}\s(?:EPS|revenue)/"
```

where `?:` denotes non-capture group

Comment: I'll give the accept to you, since you were the first answer, give me 6 minutes to allow it. I +1'd all the other answers, thanks guys!

Comment: @JohnSmith fair enough *\*smug mode\** :)

Comment: Hey I saw both of our answers as "just now."  How do you know mine wasn't first? :)

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
 $string = "FY2013 EPS, FQ 2012 revenue";
preg_match_all("/F[Y|Q]\s?\d{4}\s(?:EPS|revenue)/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an alternation for the `EPS|revenue` specifically, not `revenue` and everything else.  All together:

```
/F[Y|Q]\s?\d{4}\s(?:EPS|revenue)/
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
preg_match_all("/(F[Y|Q]\s?\d{4}\s(EPS|revenue))/", $string, $matches);
```

produces

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => FY2013 EPS
            [1] => FQ 2012 revenue
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => FY2013 EPS
            [1] => FQ 2012 revenue
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => EPS
            [1] => revenue
        )
)
```

for me